# Tensorflow Warning - Insufficient Privileges: 'cupti64_101.dll'; dlerror: cupti64_101.dll

Tags: tensorflow, cuda, gpu, warnings, privileges

Running Tensorflow 2, Cuda 10.1 on Python 3.8
Dual GPU setup. GPUs recognised by tf2, then initally had error could not find cupti64_101.dll (a CUDA library)

After copying cupti64_101.dll into libx64 (this solution from another's question), Tensorflow can now see cupti64_101.dll, but I now receive different errors:

```
2020-07-31 15:31:59.563093: E tensorflow/core/profiler/internal/gpu/cupti_tracer.cc:1408] function cupti_interface_->Subscribe( &subscriber_, (CUpti_CallbackFunc)ApiCallback, this)failed with error CUPTI_ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_PRIVILEGES
2020-07-31 15:31:59.571779: E tensorflow/core/profiler/internal/gpu/cupti_tracer.cc:1447] function cupti_interface_->ActivityRegisterCallbacks( AllocCuptiActivityBuffer, FreeCuptiActivityBuffer)failed with error CUPTI_ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_PRIVILEGES
2020-07-31 15:31:59.580274: E tensorflow/core/profiler/internal/gpu/cupti_tracer.cc:1430] function cupti_interface_->EnableCallback( 0 , subscriber_, CUPTI_CB_DOMAIN_DRIVER_API, cbid)failed with error CUPTI_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED
```

I changed the permissions on the cupti64_101.dll to give full permission for all applications. But still get these errors.
What permission(s) are required on what file(s) to resolve these error messages please?

Comment: https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-development-tools-solutions-err-nvgpuctrperm-cupti

Comment: Yes, resolved problem...thx

Comment: Please add a short answer explaining what you did to solve this

Comment: Solution - On Nvidia Control Panel, there is a Developer-Manage GPU Performance Counters section. Default toggle is to limit access to GPU preformance counters to admin users only. But you must select 'Allow acces to the GPU prformance counters to all users'. Once toggled, access permissions to the cupti dll are resolved.

Comment: The request was actually to provide a stack overflow answer, i.e. in the box below, where it says "Your Answer".  This way the question is likely to stick around as an answered question, and therefore useful for future readers.  Unanswered questions may disappear, eventually, under some circumstances.

Answer (score 5):

The privileges required relate to driver permissions. As described [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-development-tools-solutions-err-nvgpuctrperm-cupti), the CUPTI library requires the running user to have permission to access driver performance counters and profiling registers.

The solution for setting the permissions on Windows:

On Nvidia Control Panel, there is a Developer-Manage GPU Performance Counters section. Default toggle is to limit access to GPU preformance counters to admin users only. But you must select 'Allow acces to the GPU prformance counters to all users'. Once toggled, access permissions to the cupti dll are resolved. –

Comment: Thanks for adding the answer. It will be helpful to others.

Comment: Sure talonmies, I am inexperienced with stack, so still learning how to interact. good advice / feedback, thx

Comment: For those who cannot find Developer section in the Nvidia control panel: at the top, click Desktop ->  Enable Developer Settings

Comment: What should I do on Linux?

Answer (score 0):

Adding /extras/CUPTI/lib64
to the system environment variable "path" resolved the issue for me.
When i opened the visual profiler via the 'nvvp' command, it proposed this exact solution.

My CUDA path: *C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.4\extras\CUPTI\lib64*

This may not directly answer the question, but belongs here very much.

I use Windows 10 and CUDA 11.4.